# C++ literal passed to const reference leads to automatic construction

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, constants, literals

If I call the "func(const generic& ref)" with an integer as argument (instead of a 'generic' object), the constructor generic(int _a) will be called to create a new object.

```
class generic {
public:
    int a;
    generic() {}
    generic(int _a) : a(_a) {
        std::cout << "int constructor was called!";
    }
    generic(const generic& in) : a(in.a) {
        std::cout << "copy constructor was called!";
    }
};

void func(const generic& ref) {
    std::cout << ref.a;
}

int main() {
    generic g(2);
    func(g); // this is good.
    func(generic(4)); // this is good.
    func(8); // this is good...... ?
    return 0;
}
```

The last "func(8)" call creates a new object using the constructor generic(int _a). Is there a name for this kind of construction? Shouldn't the programmer explicitly construct an object before passing the argument? Like this:

```
func(generic(8));
```

Is there any benefit in passing the integer alone (other than saving time)?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast

Comment: You have a constructor that takes an `int` so the compiler will use it to make a `generic`.  If you want it to not use that constructor, use the `explicit` keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior is part of [*overload resolution*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) process - specifically.

When you call `func()`, the compiler constructs a list of candidates. There's only one candidate, `func(const generic& ref)`, so the compiler tries to figure out how to make a call.

It sees that there is no `func(int)` defined, so it tries to find a conversion path from `int` to `generic`. Since there is a constructor of `generic` that takes an `int`, and there are no other conversions allowing to perform the same call, the compiler takes the construction+call path.

The compiler checks three things, in the order from higher to lower priority:

- Exact match
- Promotion
- Conversion

This means that an exact match of the signature trumps a match that requires a promotion, and a match that requires a promotion trumps a match that needs a conversion.

See "Ranking of implicit conversion sequences" of the document linked above for information on how implicit conversions are applied.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a name for this kind of construction? Shouldn't the programmer explicitly construct an object before passing the argument?

If you don't want this to happen, you can add the [`explicit` specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) to your constructor:

```
explicit generic(int _a) : a(_a)
{
    std::cout << "int constructor was called!";
}
```

An excerpt from the cppreference page:

> A constructor that is declared without the function specifier `explicit` is called a converting constructor.

By default, implicit constructor calls are allowed in this circumstance.

> Is there any benefit in passing the integer alone (other than saving time)?

Whether you call the method with `func(8)` or `func(generic(8))` isn't going to change what code executes *given the code you have written*. If you were to add an overload of `func` that takes an `int` instead of a `generic`, then the calls would suddenly become different. So, although it is ultimately a matter of opinion, I think you are better off being explicit by using `func(generic(8))`.